# I want to prevent a duplicate entry in the list in c#

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller

private void ToggleAddCheckBoxHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
var row = sender as DataGridRow;

```
        if (row != null)
        {
            var viewModel = row.Item as EditPluginViewModel;

            if (viewModel != null)
            {
                viewModel.AddToProfile = !viewModel.AddToProfile;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to make changes in this block of code.

Comment: Before adding you can check if it is in the list.

Comment: How do you uniquely identify a plugin? What property of `Plugin x` can be compared to `Plugin y` to know it was already seen? Name? Id?

Answer (score 1):

Add if condition to check your list if contains the same plugin and if so do not add it to the list.

You can do something like the following, without testing it:

```
foreach (var plugin in plugins)
{
    if(_plugins.Any(p => p.Plugin == plugin.Plugin) == false){
        _plugins.Add(new EditPluginViewModel
        {
            Order = count++,
            IPlugin = plugin.Plugin,
            IsCritical = plugin.IsCritical
        });
    }
}
```